# Using " %c%c..." format specifier to print a string produces erratic results. Why is it so?

Tags: c, string, format, printf, format-specifiers

I am printing a **string constant** defined as a **preprocessor directive** using %s format specifier with printf() which produces the correct result.

But, then I tried some experimentation to see what will happen if I instead use "%c" and "%c%c" and "%c%c%c.." and so on as a format specifier to print the string constant.

I am not able to explain the results I am getting.

**CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define test "HeyYou!"
main()
{
   printf("\n %s", test );
   printf("\n %c", test);
   printf("\n %c%", test);  
   printf("\n %c%c%c%", test);
   printf("\n %c%c%c%c", test);
   printf("\n %c%c%c%c%c", test);
   printf("\n %c%c%c%c%c%c", test);
 }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
HeyYou!      /*<-- Desired Output and can be explained*/

             /*<---- But, I am not able to explain these outputs below*/
@`    
@`á
@`áΦ
@`áΦ
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Using `%c` and then passing a string for it is not correct, simple as that. It's undefined behavior, and so is passing too few arguments for your format specifiers. You might ask yourself why the result is inconsistent, but that's just how undefined behavior is, there's no guarantee whatsoever.

Comment: Any reasonably modern compiler should give you warnings for using invalid format specifier. If not, then please check that you are using modern compiler and you have the warnings enabled.

Comment: What you get from doing %c on the string, is casting the pointer to a char, and printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't get the whole idea:  `%s` requires a pointer to a string of characters (ended in a `\0` char) while `%c` requires the actual single char to be passed as a parameter.  When a string literal is passed, you pass actually a pointer to the character sequence and `printf` search for the end of the string when you get a `\0` char in it, while when you use `%c` you pass the characters themselves (each one in one different parameter) and printf only prints one char.

So to get the same result, you can use:

```
printf("%s", test);
```

or

```
printf("%c%c%c%c%c", test[0], test[1], test[2], test[3], test[4]);
```

(this last example will print the `\0` also, and behind it, in case it happens to be before `test[5]`)

The problem in your code is that you are passing a pointer where a character is required, so a pointer is being interpreted as a `char` data, which is wrong and the source of the undefined behaviour stated in other answers.